# How can I check if an element exists?

Tags: react-native, map-function

I'm doing an application that downloads some images and save them in the phone memory. But sometimes that list of images changes so I need to delete the ones that are no more necessary. For that I have a json with all my data, including the current images names, and I want to compare the images that I have stored in my phone with the ones that are on my json. When it founds a image that does not match with an image of the json, it deletes it.

```
deleteImages(){
    let img = false;
    const x = this.state.data.monuments.length-1;
    const y = this.state.data.monuments[x].monuments.length-1;
    const z = this.state.data.monuments[x].monuments[y].pois.length-1;

return (
  RNFS.readDir(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath)
  .then( result => {
      result.map((r, index) => {
        this.state.data.monuments.map((i, indexCategorias) => i.monuments.map((j, indexMonuments) => {
          if (r.name == j.image_md5 + '.jpg'){
            img = true;
          }

          j.pois.map((k, indexPois) => {
            if (r.name == k.image_md5 + '.jpg'){
              img = true;
            }

            if (indexCategorias==x && indexMonuments==y && indexPois==z && img == false){
              RNFS.unlink(r.path)
                .then(() => {
                  console.log('FILE DELETED');
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err.message);
                });
            }

            if(indexCategorias==x && indexMonuments==y && indexPois==z && img == true){
              img = false;
            }

          })


        }))
      }) //end of map function
  }) //end of .then(result)

)
} //end of deleteImages
```

My code is working, but the way I done this is really terrible. With the RNFS library I have a method 'exists' that finds if a determined string exist or not on the directory, there isnt something similar on the map function? like map.exist ou map.has? I just want to make my code more efficient.

Comment: Hey there, if I understand you correctly you are simply looking for a more elegant way to work with arrays? 
You should check out the MDN docs on Array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Some viable methods might be `reduce` or `find` or `includes`

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I want something to check if an element in the phone directory it's on the array.

For this particular case I want something like:
this.state.data.monuments.map((i, indexCategorias) => i.monuments.map(j => j.includes(x => (x.image_md5 + '.jpg') === r.name))) 

But it isnt working, what am I doing bad? Thks

Comment: Check the return value of the methods you're using.
`map` for example returns a new array with the result of the callback function. `includes` on the other hand simply returns a boolean value.

Make sure to play around a bit with the methods without having the callback structure of your sample code.

Comment: The return I want is a boolean value. The problem is that my 'j' is an object and I think that the includes doesnt work on objects. The filter method works but it returns a array, and I dont want that. 
Don't know if there is a solution...

Thank you for the help tho :)